# can anyone help identify this?

Tags: trees, flowering, tropical

[image]

Hi, I grew this beauty from a black pod like seed that drifts often onto our Beach here in Mayaro, trinidad. The leaves grew slowly, and the pod size ranges, but could be as big as an adult fist, or as small as a childs fist, with the growth shoot coming out at the tip, similar to a tea mangrove, but more ridges and black, as opposed to reddish brown.
I can't find anything at all that looks like it online, but it's seeds are common on my beach, so I assume it's either south american, or African.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to venture a guess I would say this is Pachira aquatica otherwise known as money tree.

Comment: Pictures of the flowers (the same as the OP's picture) and nuts here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pachira_aquatica